# jQuery - How to animate text simultaneously to color change transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, coloranimation

I need to create a smooth transition of movement and color change. Right now, the text first is being animated, and only **after** animation end the color change transition occurs. How can I change the color of the text **during** the movement?

This is the HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger center-block" id="btn">start animation</button>
<div id="meterText" class="col-centered"></div> <!-- animated text -->
```

CSS:

```
#meterText{
    display:none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 211px;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var counter=0;

$("#btn").on('click',function(event){
    counter++;
    console.log(event.target.id + " was clicked");
    switch(counter){
        case 1:{
            $("#meterText").text("first transition");
            $("#meterText").hide().fadeIn();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{

            $("#meterText").animate({'marginTop':"-=83px"});
            $("#meterText").text("second transition");
            $("#meterText").animate({color: "#FFD700"});
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            $("#meterText").text("third transition");   
            $("#meterText").animate({'marginTop':"-=68px"});
            $("#meterText").animate({color: "#44c767"});
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/1045/)

Comment: Pass color change also inside first animation function

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/1047/)

Comment: Or you can pass queue: false as an argument, if you want to keep the animations separate. http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/1048/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by Default animate in jquery works one by one .. So if you have 2 animate .. the second one run after the first one finished 
I wondered why you used the code in separated lines while you can simplified it to just one line

```
$("#meterText").animate({'marginTop':"-=83px",color: "#FFD700"}).text("second transition");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just execute the animations simultaneously:

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K9LpL/1046/)

```
$("#meterText").animate({'marginTop':"-=83px",color: "#FFD700"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i advice you to use css for auto transition use this css in your css selector :

```
-moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
 transition-duration: 0.6s;
```

and then in your jquery use .css instead of .animate and it will work smoothly and you can set the duration from the css 
check out the snippet

```js
var counter=0;

$("#kickme").on('click',function(event){
 counter++;
 console.log(event.target.id + " was clicked");
 switch(counter){
  case 1:{
   $("#meterText").text("first transition");
   $("#meterText").hide().fadeIn();
   break;
  }
  case 2:{
   
   $("#meterText").css({'marginTop':"-=83px","color": "#FFD700"});
   $("#meterText").text("second transition");
   break;
  }
  case 3:{
   $("#meterText").text("third transition");
            $("#meterText").css({'marginTop':"-=68p","color": "#44c767"});
   break;
  }
 }
 
});
```

```css
#meterText{
 display:none;
 width: 50px;
 height: 10px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 211px;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: red;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.6s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.6s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.6s;
transition-duration: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger center-block" id="kickme">kick me!</button>

<div id="meterText" class="col-centered"></div> <!-- meter's text -->
```

Comment: Nice solution, it seems it breaks the `fadeIn` animation of jQuery. How to fix this?